# Silverlight 5 - 3D - RenderModeReason - TemporarilyUnavailable

Tags: silverlight, 3d, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying to create a simple Silverlight 3d application...

I have a good enough PC, but when I run the Silverlight application I get this:

*RenderModeReason - TemporarilyUnavailable*... **WTF is that? o_O**

PS: The sample 3D applications where made by MS and are compiling and working.

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to use 3D acceleration in your app (and all the XNA namespaces), you must enable HardwareAcceleration during plugin initialization. Fortunately, it's easy:

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      [...]
      <param name="enableGPUAcceleration" value="true" />
      [...]
</object>
```

To enable GPU acceleration for Out of browser apps, set the enable GPU acceleration option on the project property page.

Comment: it's enabled... if you don't set EnableGPUAcceleration to True you will get "HardwareAccelerationDisabled" (or something like that).. i get TemporaryUnavalible state..

Comment: `GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.RenderModeChanged += new EventHandler<RenderModeChangedEventArgs>(Current_RenderModeChanged);`

Comment: But when you put a break point in the page constructor, do the Microsoft.XNA.Graphics.Silverlight.GraphicsDeviceManager.Current.RenderMode evaluates to TemporaryUnavailable? And is your Draw event handler called? (I expect it isn't...)